# create a slanted rectangle drawable in android xml

Tags: android, xml

I would like to create rectangle drawable then rotate it so top right side appear  slanted, i would eventually overlay over rounded corner image ,in effort to create a copy of the image below , using some drawable  [image]

am hoping for using with xml , but it just slanted and edge never touch other side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item >
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="19.5"
        android:toDegrees="-19.5"
        android:pivotX="-50%"
        android:pivotY="0%"
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

create a custom Drawable that draws the shape: but again i fail , would love any help ? thank you

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
int width = this.getBounds().width();
int height = this.getBounds().height();
double angle = 19.5 * (Math.PI / 180.0);
double offsetX = height * Math.tan(angle);

Path path = new Path();
Paint paint = new Paint();
path.moveTo(0, 0);
path.lineTo(width, 0);
path.lineTo(width, height);
path.lineTo((int)offsetX, height);
path.close();

paint.setColor(_color);
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```